ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'craft_structure'
I've installed craft-text-detector but I cannot import craft_structure:
pip install craft-text-detector

from craft_structure.detection import detect, get_detector

Output:
Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_33796\44427766.py in <module>
      1 import torch
----> 2 from craft_structure.detection import detect, get_detector
      3 
      4 device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
      5 craft = get_detector("models/craft_mlt_25k.pth", device)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'craft_structure'


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What version of craft-text-detector did you install?

contact the maintainer of the package.

Make sure folder is added into PYTHONPATH. Run: echo %PYTHONPATH% in your terminal if you see folder where your project is located there.

Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages

I don't believe that the module  you're importing exists here. The package does not expose any module named  'craft_structure'. Please see here for available functionality.
